# Evaluating prediction extremely slow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN using the following placeholders...

```
# mnist data image of shape [batch_size, 28, 28, 1].
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])

# 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes.
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

I train it within a session, and as I must reshape the data every time before I feed the data to the placeholder, here is roughly what I am doing...

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    for epoch in range(25):

        total_batch = int(features.train.num_examples/500)

        avg_cost = 0

        for i in range(total_batch):

            batch_xs, batch_ys = features.train.next_batch(10)

            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x:batch_xs.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]), y:batch_ys})

   ...
   ...
```

As you can see I am reshaping the data before I feed it to the placeholder. The CNN seems to work fine, however an issue arises when I try to calculate the accuracy of the prediction. I am predicting it using a softmax tensor and my `logits` layer...

```
# Logits Layer.
# Create a dense layer with 10 neurons => 10 classes
# Output has a shape of [batch_size, 10]
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

# Softmax layer for deriving probabilities.
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
```

...so after all the training take place, this is how I calculate the predictions...

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
...
...
features = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
...
...

# list of booleans to determine the correct predictions
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

print(correct_prediction.eval({x:features.test.images.reshape([10000, 28, 28, 1]), y:features.test.labels}))
```

Unfortunately, I must convert every `features` data into the correct format since the placeholder `x` only accepts the format `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]`. There are 10,000 images and labels. When I do this, my computer slows down tremendously and a lot of computation is used, and I need to restart my computer every time. Clearly converting them into this format is not very computationally friendly.

What's a better way to do this that doesn't cause my computer to crash? I've used the following code for other Neural Networks...

```
print(correct_prediction.eval({x:features.test.images, y:features.test.labels}))
```

...but I've never had this issue which leads me to believe the cause is stemming from the `reshape` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might need to take a look at the whole script, but from the provided snippets, I think the issue is that you're pushing the *whole* test set for evaluation at once.

Note that not only it allocates `10000*28*28*4` (30Mb) for the input tensor and its pooled transformations, the convolutional layer performs approx `10000*25*25*1*filter_size` convolutions across the whole batch (the first layer alone). It is very computationally expensive, and that's what most probably takes the whole time, not `reshape`.

You should perform test evaluation by batch. This is simplified code, need to be more careful to compute it correctly with arbitrary `batch_size`:

```
total_accuracy = 0.0
for batch_xs, batch_ys in iterate_batches(features.test, batch_size):
  accuracy = correct_prediction.eval({x: batch_xs.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]), y: batch_ys})
  total_accuracy += np.mean(accuracy)
total_batches = features.test.num_examples / batch_size
total_accuracy /= total_batches
```

But it should work for `batch_size=10` or `batch_size=100`.

Comment: This is helpful, I am able to evaluate the prediction but I am getting an odd number for my `total_accuracy`, but at least I have an idea of what to do.

Comment: Also, here is [My Github](https://github.com/Bolboa), the entire script is located under Adversarial Images 2 in case you want to take a look.